# Get class name using Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, css-selectors

I am trying to get the products' ratings of a webpage. The rating is in `<bl-rating>`:

[image]

To get the title of the product, I did:

```
'title':product.css('h2::text').get()
```

Is there a way to get the rating (4.714...) using a similar technique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rating isn't text node value rather attribute value.So You have to invoke `::attr(rating)` instead of `::text` to get that value as string/text.

```
'rating':product.css('bl-rating::attr(rating)').get()
```

**Using an xpath expression:**

After iterating over an array/list of elements, the subsequent xpath expression would be a relative expression (`.//`)

```
'rating':product.xpath('.//bl-rating/@rating').get()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is more for anyone who might find this answer in the future.

You can also extract the `rating` value using an `xpath` expression.

For Example:

```
'rating': response.xpath('//bl-rating/@rating').get()
```